# add-on options of product in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to add a product with add-on options, and we should be able to manage the inventory of main product as well as add-ons. Also, its not compulsory to select add ons.
We want to add product [Similiar to this product](http://www.reefgeek.com/lighting/t5-fluorescent/ati/dimmable-sunpower-fixtures/48-8x54w-dimmable-sunpower-t5-high-output-fixture-w-controller.html#). 
I have tried to implement it in two ways:
1. Using configurable products: Added a configurable product and added associated products. [Problem: Associated products becomes compulsory to select and also we are not able to manage inventory of the main product.
2. Using Bundled Products: Added a Bundled product and then assigned associated products to it. But here also we can't manage the inventory of the main bundled product.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bundled product  with custom changes. I dont think magento provide such functionality by default

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Jarial. Yes, magento do not provide add-on functionality by default. And if we use bundled products for this purpose then we are unable to manage the inventory of bundled product independently. So what I did is created a simple product with the same name as bundled product and made it default with attribute name "Base Item". Now in code I applied a check if attribute name is "Base Item" then hide the item. Now if someone buys the product the simpe product with the same name is automatically assigned. Now we can easily manage the inventory of simple product.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't a bundle product work for you?
You don't need to manage stock of the bundle product, only for the simples that are contained within.
You can set one bundle option with only the simple product that is your main product in and make it 'not user selectable qty' and 'required', then you have another product option underneath with your options, these can be a drop down or multi select and you make these 'not required' so they can choose these if they like.
Does that make sense?

Comment: I have already tried this but got no success. Okay let me explain in detail. In my situation the bundled product is itself product. Example: Suppose i want to sell Laptop. Laptop will be main product, then i want few drop-downs in front of main product (laptop), like first drop-down will contain the list of keyboards (of different features) next drop-down will contain list of speakers. From where we can select keyboard and speakers, which are optional. Note here Laptop is main product, i need to manage its inventory and also keyboard and speakers are add-ons which may be separate products.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial explains exactly what you need:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: I have created configurable product but it is not fulfilling my requirements as explained in question.

Comment: If the default options of magento are not fulfilling your wishes you should create your own module or search on magento connect for one that does. (Because the configurable product is probably the closest you can get to what you are looking for)